# Compare data in two cells to look for a partial match

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably quite a simple script to write, but my coding is terrible.

I have a column with A list of surnames, and column B with file names that should contain the surname somewhere in the string.

i.e.

```
A      B
Smith   10 0950 Smith 10101950
Jones   10 0955 Jones 10051942
Thomas  10 1008 Thoma 01051972
```

I need to check that the spelling of the surname in column A is found within the string in column B, and highlight the row where there is a mismatch.

In this instance the third line for Thomas would be highlighted.

There should be no more than 1000 rows to be checked.

I cannot find a piece of code anywhere that will do this for me.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim numrows as long
numrows = Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row


'loop over all rows
for i = 1 to numrows
    'instr function returns 0 if string 2 is not found within string 1. in this case, if the value in col A, is not found within col B
    if instr(1, cells(i,2).formulaR1C1, Cells(i,1).formulaR1C1) = 0 then
        Cells(i,1).entireRow.interior.color = RGB(255,255,0) 'highlight row
    end if
next
```

Welcome to SO, you're correct, it was simple. however please do note that according to the help page on "on topic answers" - "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." do keep that in mind in future posts :)

also, don't forget to mark as answer if this works for you :)